# Html5 video only loads image but no play button

Tags: xml, html, xslt, video

```
<video>
      <source>
           <xsl:attribute name = "src">
                <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
      </source>
</video>
```

This is my `xhtml` construction so that I can have an html5 player inside of my `xml`. However, when I load the page, I have an image but no audio or video at all. I can right click the image and click loop but the "play" and "pause" options are unclickable. Also, when I try to load this through an `iframe`, the videos automatically start playing which is not what I want. How do I make the videos actually be videos?

Edit: If it helps, I am loading 150 videos and stopping execution after the load of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `controls` attribute to your `<video>` tag (if it's there then controls are shown, if not then they are hidden)

```
<video controls>
      <source>
...
```